# Salesforce CLI is not retrieving permission set metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, cli

I am trying to retrieve metadata from a sandbox instance to prepare a deployment. Flows, Custom Objects, etc. are getting retrieved, but permission sets are not.

In my package.xml file, I tried the wild card and explicitly designated members:

```
<types>
  <members>*</members>
  <name>PermissionSet</name>
</types>
```

My CLI command looks like this:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve `
    -r retrieved `
    -k $manifestFile `
    -w 10 `
    -u $username `
    -a 57.0
```

No errors. No warnings. No permission set metadata.

Comment: Have you verified that permission sets are not in the forceignore file?

Comment: Confirmed permission sets are not in forceignore file.

Comment: For debugging I referenced a pared-down package.xml and renamed package-debug.xml and the permissions sets were retrieved. Referenced the original XML file and it failed again.

Comment: I am now retrieving the permission sets now. The only thing I can't think of is my XML was not well formed. I am seeing this behavior with other objects, so I maybe I can find a root cause soon.